# Как собрать JMD?

Tags: java

Добрый день. Пытаюсь скомпилировать JMD (https://github.com/contra/JMD)
Релиз использовать не могу, он сломан. 
Последний комит исправляет проблему, но собрать я не могу по какой то причине.
При помощи gradlew build без единой ошибки проходит компиляция. В jmd-cli, jmd-core, jmd-gui появляются собранные .jar файлы.. но проблема в том, что JMD просто представляет собой один .jar файл. А тут их три и все не имеют MainClass'a. 
Подскажите, может где я что напутал?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`jmd-cli-1.6.jar` переименовываешь в `jmd.jar`, потом кидаешь в папку с `JMDGUI.exe`.
один из вариантов запуска:

```
java -jar JMD.jar "test.jar" renamer true
```